# iOS 7 Dev - Minimizing app causes UIWebView inline YouTube Player to stop playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, youtube

I'm working on a project that plays YouTube videos, inline in a UIWebView. What I'm trying to do is to continue playing the app's audio, even when the home button is pressed (or focus is off the app in any way). I've done the following (as suggested from searching my question here):

1. Made sure Audio and Fetch were included in my info.plist for Background Modes
2. Made sure my ViewController that contained the WebView is registered to receive remote control events:

   `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];`

   `[self becomeFirstResponder];`
3. Messed with the AVAudioSession (sharedSession) and set the category to playback.

None of these things worked. Either I'm doing one of them incorrectly (which I doubt--I've found several "solutions" here that have worked for other people but not for my particular case).

I have a feeling this might have something to do with the way the WebView plays audio. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add BackgroundMode: "Audio And AirPlay".

It's the following key in your plist:

```
`<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
<string>audio</string>`
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but unfortunately I've already tried that (see point 1).